# Dividing planes with lines and spheres

Tags: problem-solving

**What is the greatest number of parts a plane can be divided into using $n$ infinite straight lines? What about $n$ circles?**

**Can you generalise this into 3-dimensional space, planes and spheres?**

For lines, I got $U_{n+1}=U_n+n,$ with $U_0=1.$
And for circles, I got $U_{n+1}=U_n+2n,$ with $U_0=1$ and $U_1=2.$

Am I right so far?

Comment: Check my edit to see how it's done. Note that we need the braces when we want a subscript longer than one character.

Comment: @Cameron Buie - Thank you :)